# Add babel to plain tex [Texlive - Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: texlive, languages, plain-tex, ubuntu

To add babel to plain tex in my previous Ubuntu installation I used to do the following:

- edit the file `/etc/texmf/fmt.d/10texlive-base.cnf`
- change the line `tex tex - tex.ini` into `tex tex language.dat bplain.ini`
- update available formats with `update-fmtutil`
- create tex with `fmtutil-sys --byfmt tex`

Now in Ubuntu 16.04 things have changed and this procedure does not work any longer. 
I tried to look in texlive documentation how to get this, but I could not figure it out.
The question is then how can I get the same effect in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What does not work anymore?

Comment: The point is that in ubuntu 16.04 the structure of `/etc/texmf` has been deeply changed and there is no longer the utility `texconfig-sys` which I used to modify the file which contains the line `tex tex - tex.ini`, so I couldn't figure out how to configure tex. Eventually I somehow did it: I created a new file, say `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/local.cnf` containing the line `tex tex language.dat bplain.ini` and then I run `fmtutil-sys --byfmt tex`. I do not know if this is the "correct" way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct method. Fmtutil.cnf files are now stacked, so all of them are read and later override earlier ones. Thus your setting overrides the standard in texmf-dist. That is explained in the docs in of tex-common

Comment: I had a look at the docs but I couldn't find it. Maybe I had a too quick look... but the documentation is so HUGE!  :(

Comment: I added an answer with three correct solution ;-)

Comment: The answer also contains a link to the place where this is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way as documented in `/usr/share/doc/tex-common/TeX-on-Debian.*` (Section 2.4.3) is to add new `fmtutil.cnf` file in either `TEXMFLOCAL/web2c` or `TEXMFSYSCONFIG/web2c`, that is either `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/` or `/etc/texmf/web2c/` containing the new or updated format definitions.

Files should **not** be put into `/etc/texmf/fmtutil.cnf/` anymore.